# Retrieve used barcode reader from several devices plugged

Tags: c#, .net, windows, barcode, barcode-scanner

I'm working on an access control windows application, I'm using .Net and a simple Barcode readers.

In my app, I'd like to use 2 barcode readers installed on the same computer in differents USB ports

- First to log entrance.
- Second to log exit.

How can I retrieve which Barcode reader was been used to log ? (the one plugged on USB port 1 or 2)

[>> here is an explanatory diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jl4hX.jpg)

Comment: As written, without any code or any other details, there's really no way to answer. Please edit your question to be specific (and to have a specific question). Right now, it reads as a query about a general requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i added a diagram for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

@Abd13t,

If you are using the scanner in keyboard wedge mode and both scanners are going to be reading the same barcode, one way to do this would be to add different prefixes that your scanner appends to the data event.

If you using an OPOS or POS for .NET implementation your data events should be associated with a specific device.

In order to help you further, we would need more details.

Terry Warwick, Microsoft

Comment: Thanks for your response, i added a diagram for more detail

Comment: I think we get the concept, but we would need more details regarding technical details of the .NET application to help you further.